# NG-CLICK simple function in Angular not passing through variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have a defined a basic controller which has a function called setSector (at the bottom)

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.sectors =
    {
        "Sector": [
            {
                "sectorDesc": "London and South East",
                "sectorCode": "LSE",
                "SectorPPM": {
                    "Total": "10329",
                    "OnTime": "9195",
                    "Late": "1134",
                    "CancelVeryLate": "206",
                    "PPM": {
                        "rag": "A",
                        "text": "89"
                    },
                    "RollingPPM": {
                        "trendInd": "-",
                        "rag": "R",
                        "text": "83"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "sectorDesc": "Long Distance",
                "sectorCode": "LD",
                "SectorPPM": {
                    "Total": "1383",
                    "OnTime": "1159",
                    "Late": "224",
                    "CancelVeryLate": "68",
                    "PPM": {
                        "rag": "R",
                        "text": "83"
                    },
                    "RollingPPM": {
                        "trendInd": "+",
                        "rag": "G",
                        "text": "92"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "sectorDesc": "Regional",
                "sectorCode": "REG",
                "SectorPPM": {
                    "Total": "5348",
                    "OnTime": "4678",
                    "Late": "670",
                    "CancelVeryLate": "196",
                    "PPM": {
                        "rag": "R",
                        "text": "87"
                    },
                    "RollingPPM": {
                        "trendInd": "=",
                        "rag": "R",
                        "text": "87"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "sectorDesc": "Scotland",
                "sectorCode": "SCO",
                "SectorPPM": {
                    "Total": "2026",
                    "OnTime": "1861",
                    "Late": "165",
                    "CancelVeryLate": "41",
                    "PPM": {
                        "rag": "A",
                        "text": "91"
                    },
                    "RollingPPM": {
                        "trendInd": "+",
                        "rag": "G",
                        "text": "94"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    $scope.currentSector = null;

    $scope.setSector = function (sectorCode) {
        $scope.currentSector = $scope.sectors[sectorCode];
    };
}
```

which is called from my index file.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>PPM Viewer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>PPM Dashboard</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="sector in sectors.Sector">
            <a href="" ng-click="setSector(sector.sectorCode)">{{sector.sectorCode}} - {{sector.sectorDesc}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p>
        Current sector : {{currentSector.sectorDesc}}
        Current code : {{currentSector.sectorCode}}
    </p>

</div>

</body>
```

When you click on the sectors in the UL list, the name of the clicked on sector is supposed to  appear at the bottom, but for some reason the function is not passing back anything.

I am sure it is due to needing to specify the $scope.sectors.Sector somewhere in the function. but nothing I try will work. I am still quite new to angular and scopes, and think that I need to force the scope to go to a deeper level.. just not sure how

Can anyone advise how I can make the function... function! =)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So neater way of doing this would be to use the $index functionality of Angular. Try changing your code to:

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="sector in sectors.Sector">
       <a href="" ng-click="setSector($index)">{{sector.sectorCode}} - {{sector.sectorDesc}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.setSector = function (index) {
   $scope.currentSector = $scope.sectors.Sector[index];
};
```

$index in an ng-repeat states the index of an item in an array, which you can use in the javascript to select the correct sector from your array.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $scope.currentSector, instead of .sectorDesc

So either change your function *or* template:

**Template:**

```
Current sector : {{currentSector}}
```

**Or function:**

```
 $scope.currentSector = {};
 $scope.setSector = function (sectorCode) {
    $scope.currentSector.sectorDesc = $scope.sectors[sectorCode];
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I have expanded the front end example a little. The function is supposed to pull in details for the entire sector, not just reflect the code that has been clicked as I will also be listing the info for the PPM data.

I have therefore tried your suggested function, with no success. The page just stays blank. I have checked the console, and there are no errors. just.. nothing.